# ORM: Article, revisions and main revisions

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

What is the best practice in ORM to store articles and their revisions? When storing in SQL by myself, I used to have following structure:

```
 articles [id, parent_id, name, text]
```

and by parent_id I could easily recognize parent article:

```
 SELECT * FROM articles WHERE parent_id = 0;
```

would select parent revisions and,

```
 SELECT * FROM articles WHERE parent_id = 330;
```

would select all the revisions of article #330.

What is the right way of doing this in ORM? Shall I rather have:

1. Integer parentId
2. Article parentArticle
3. List revisions

I will appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

translate your sql to hibernate/jpa entity:

```
@Entity
@Table.....
public class Article {

    @Id
    @Column
    private Integer id,

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parentArticle")        
    private Set<Article> childArticles;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
    private Article parentArticle

    @Column
    private String name,text
    ...
```

I don't know your exact requirement. Have you checked hibernate entity auditing? is it helpful for you? it will store a copy with revision number everytime you change the "article".

link of hibernate envers:
http://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/index.html